# Using replaceState() (or something else) to update the state object rather than replace it

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

Is there some technique I can use (perhaps something clever with `replaceState()`) to update the history state object rather than replace it?

Given an existing state object that looks like this:

```
{ prop1:someValue, prop2:someOtherValue }
```

I want to be able to call something that will modify `prop1` but leave `prop2` alone.

I guess I'm really looking for a `modifyState()` rather than `replaceState()`.

This would be trivial if I knew what the value of `prop2` was, but I don't.  Firefox allows you to read `history.state` directly, so I could find the value out on Firefox and go with `replaceState()`. However that won't work for Chrome, Safari, et al. because (as far as I can tell) they don't allow direct access to `history.state`.

Is there some way for me to modify the state object as described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) allows for state manipulation via replaceState since Chrome 8.

I currently have a similar issue where only a part of the state needs to be modified. This is accomplished by cloning the current state data, changing the value and then calling replaceState.

```
History.replaceState(newState, null, oldState.url);
```